# An acting condition for a superposition operator from $H^1(\Omega)$ to $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

If i take $v\in H^1(\Omega)$ where
$$
H^1(\Omega)=\{u\in L^2(\Omega), \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\in L^2(\Omega), i=1,\ldots,N\}
$$

$\Omega$ is bounded open set from $\mathbb{R}^N$

What is the sufficient condition for a real function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to have that $f\circ v\in H^1(\Omega)$

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is stated in the paper

*Moshe Marcus and Victor J. Mizel*, MR 531975 [**Complete characterization of functions which act, via superposition, on Sobolev spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1998689), *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **251** (1979), 187--218.

as Theorem 1 (note that $T_f$ is the superposition operator corresponding to $f$ and that the paper assumes $\Omega$ to satisfy the cone condition):

> Suppose that $\Omega$ is bounded. Let $f \colon \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ be a Borel function and let $p$, $r$ be two such that $1 \le r \le p < N$. Then $T_f$ maps $W^{1,p}(\Omega)^m$ into $W^{1,r}(\Omega)$ if and only if the following conditions hold:
>
> 1. $f$ is locally Lipschitz in $\mathbb R^m$
> 2. The first order partial derivatives of $f$ satisfy the inequality
>      $$ \left| \frac {\partial f}{\partial \xi_i}(\xi) \right| \le a_0(1+|\xi|^\nu)\ \text{a.e. in $\mathbb R^m$, $i = 1,\dotsc,m$}$$
>      where $a_0$ is a constant and $\nu = N(p-r)/(r(N-p))$.
>
> If $N < p$ (or $N = 1$ and $1 \le p$) and $1 \le r \le p$ then $T_f$ maps $W^{1,p}(\Omega)^m$ into $W^{1,r}(\Omega)$ if and only if condition 1 holds.

The theorem goes on to state that under these circumstances $T_f$ is a continuous operator; bounds are established for its image, too. The case of unbounded $\Omega$ is considered in the same paper, see Theorem 3.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious sufficient condition for $v\mapsto f(v)$ to map $H^1(\Omega)$ to itself ($\Omega$ bounded) is $f$ globally Lipschitz, i.e. $f'\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Add $f(0)=0$ for general $\Omega$.

This condition is also necessary for $N\ge2$, I think (but don't ask me for a reference, that's folk wisdom, although it must be proven somewhere).

Comment: this answer is on contradiction with the answer of @Bazin no?

Comment: No, Bazin is right: for polynomials, only affine functions (polynomials of degree 1) work for $N\ge2$.

Comment: and how we find that $f'\in L^{\infty}$ please

Comment: Lipschitz continuity: $\sup_{s<t}|\frac{f(s)-f(t)}{s-t}|<\infty$

Comment: I man how we see that we must choose this condition

Comment: Apply the chain rule; $\nabla(f\circ v)=f'(v)\nabla v$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just a long comment: if you want this property for any $f$ polynomial (or any smooth $f$), you will need $H^1$ to be an algebra, which is true only in  1D ($N=1$). More generally, $H^s$ is an algebra iff $s>N/2$.

Now the previous comment is also pointing out that, excluding the trivial case where $f$ is an affine function, you will essentially need your Sobolev space to be an algebra, which requires $s>N/2$. Note that there is a nice proof, using Bernstein polynomials, that these Sobolev spaces ($H^s$ with $s>N/2$) are stable by composition by a general smooth function $f$.

Comment: So we must consider $N<2$ ! it means $N=1$. and what about $f$ please and where i can found the proof ?

Comment: @Bazin Could you give a reference for the proof using Bernstein polynomials?

Comment: Look at Guy Métivier's "Para-Differential Calculus ... systems", Edizioni della Normale, 2008.